# iOS, Swift: animation controlled by gesture

Tags: ios, animation, swift, core-animation, uigesturerecognizer

I trying to find a way for connecting user interaction (pan gesture) with animation. I want to control animation progress by dragging view (or just by finger panning on the screen).

I think I can make this by using Core Animation, but I didn't find any similar to my needs example.
I have a `CGPath`, that I want to draw.
I know that there are `strokeStart` and `strokeEnd` property that is animatable and perfectly acceptable for my needs in the "drawing" point of view.

Using layer with given `path` property I can animate this path with CABasicAnimation

```
layer.path = myPath
//... layer configuration
let pathAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
pathAnimation.duration = 2
pathAnimation.fromValue = 0
pathAnimation.toValue = 1
layer.addAnimation(pathAnimation, forKey: "strokeEndAnimation")
```

Here we can see animation from the first path point to the last consequentially.

Okay, but I need to somehow control this animation with gesture.
Let's say, if we pan finger on the screen to the right, our path animation draws straight ahead (e.g strokeStart = 0 and strokeEnd = 1) and if we pan from right to left we will see backward animation (like rewind) (e.g. strokeStart = 1 and strokeEnd = 0).

I know, how to get gesture direction, translationInView, velocityInView and I want to animate this in changed state, not end. (`UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed`)

But I don't know how I can combine control from gesture to animation because of this troubles:

- duration of animation. (I don't know how fast or how slow gesture would be)
- how I need to implement animation because calls are very frequent in changed state

I looked to 
`animateWithDuration:delay:usingSpringWithDamping:initialSpringVelocity:options:animations:completion:`

but duration question rises again.

Hope somebody can help me, ask me if you misunderstood something and I'll try to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let's say, if we pan finger on the screen to the right, our path animation draws straight ahead (e.g strokeStart = 0 and strokeEnd = 1) and if we pan from right to left we will see backward animation (like rewind) (e.g. strokeStart = 1 and strokeEnd = 0).

If I understand you correctly, the solution is to freeze the animation by setting the layer's `speed` to 0 and then setting the "frame" of the animation by setting the layer's `timeOffset`.

Comment: See, for example, this code from my book, where I freeze a path animation and then allow the user to govern the change with a slider: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch04p160frozenAnimation/FrozenAnimationTest/ViewController.swift

Comment: thanks for your response matt, I'm trying to implement your solution. You're doing a good job with your books. I appeal to them not for the first time.

Comment: By the way, I think the very thing you are talking about is actually illustrated in the WWDC 2014 video on Building Interruptible and Responsive Application.s

Comment: I already watched it, it's very close but can't be used in my question (or I'm misunderstood something). Your answer and example are what I'm looking for. Thanks.